# ZSH no encuentra PHP

Tags: php, xampp, zsh

Estoy usando **zsh** en Linux Mint.

Cuando busco la versión de PHP en la terminal, aparece ésto:

```
php -v
zsh: command not found: php
```

He usado el comando **whereis** para hallar la ruta de instalación de PHP y no encuentra nada. Tampoco tengo la carpeta PHP en */usr/bin/*

PS: He instalado la versión de XAMPP de Bitnami, y esta es la ruta donde lo he instalado: */home/carlos/lampstack-7.3.11-0*

Comment: Y hmm y con which php?

Comment: Instalé manualmente PHP. Problema solucionado.